# Breaking out from lambda using return@label not working in Kotlin for "string".chars()

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, foreach, return

Following code tries to break out from `forEach` lambda when ascii value of character is 59. It however **does not compile**.

```
fun foo() {
    run label@ {
        "abcd".chars().forEach {
            if (it == 59) return@label
            print(it)
        }
        print("completed forEach")
    }
}
```

However, it **compiles** if forEach is used directly on characters instead of calling `chars()` method to get ascii values as shown below

```
fun foo() {
    run label@ {
        "abcd".forEach {
            if (it == 'd') return@label
            print(it)
        }
        print("completed forEach")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because `chars()` returns an IntStream, which is not an Iterable so the Kotlin inline function `Iterable.forEach` is not available. You’re calling a Java function named `forEach` that is not inline. You can only break out of lambdas that are passed to inline functions and whose functional parameter is not marked `crossinline`.

Answer (score 0):

Following change worked

```
"abcd".chars().toArray().forEach {...}
```

Comment: Use `asSequence` instead of `toArray` to avoid the wasteful array copy.

Comment: Great suggestion thanks @Tenfour04